# Using jQuery's Ajax to do instantaneous calculation on the view in mvc2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery

I have got a total product page which shows the total amount of the products added to the basket , What I want to do is to add a promo text field where users can add the promo code to get certain discounts , the promo code are save in the database with discount rate. So if a client enters the code , and press the promo button the system should check for the valid promo code and then do instaneous calculation by deducting the total price with the discount rate . Is this can be done using jQuery Ajax or is there any other possible solution for it , Any help or tutorial will be highly appreciated. Cheers

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#promo").change(function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                var number = $('promoNumber').val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Booking/Review',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {number:textbox},
                    success: function (data) {
                                  if (data["success"]) {
                                  alert(data)
                                  }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

    <%using (Html.BeginForm())
{ %>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td> <input type="button" id="promo" value="Promo" /> </td>
                <td> <%: Html.TextBox("promoNumber") </td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td>
                  <div class="totalCost">
                   <label><b>Total Amount:</b></label> <%: String.Format("{0:c}", ViewBag.TotalAmount)%> <br /></div>
                 </td></tr>

                 </table> }%>
```

Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Review(int number)//this parameter is my selected checkbox value.I have to get this value from ajax
    {
        IVoucherRepository voucherResp = new VoucherRepository();
        IQueryable<Voucher> getVoucher = voucherResp.GetVouchers(number);
         //first check if the code is there or not else return error
         int discount = 0;
         foreach (var number in getVoucher) 
         {
         discount = number.discount;//Thats the discount number
         }
       //after getting the discount code i need to pass that to ViewBag.TotalAmount to do calculation
         ViewData["Data"] = "success";
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: This can certainly be done with Javascript / AJAX.  jQuery would be a good starting point.  Alternatively, Knockout.js is a framework based largely around accomplishing this goal.  You should begin by choosing a framework and playing around with it.  Do you have relevant code from what you have and attempts you've made it solve this issue?

Comment: Yes, but you are also using jQuery (from your tags).  Fundamentally, yes, when the user inputs a coupon code, you can fire-off an AJAX request which will return the relevant price discount and update the field appropriately.  That's about as specific an answer can be given based on your question without any other relevant code.

Comment: I want to avoid postback , i can do the calculation using postback for the button , but i dont want to render the whole page, just for updating the total price.

Comment: Yes, AJAX will prevent that.  Code man, I need code to assist you.  Abstractly, this is fairly simple.  But the devil is in the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen a problem when you're posting your data to the controller:

```
var number = $('promoNumber').val();
```

and then:

```
data: {number:textbox},
```

What is textbox?
You should refer to your **promoNumber** like this in jQuery:

```
var number = $('#promoNumber').val();
```

This is what I would do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#promo").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Booking/Review',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { number: $("#promoNumber").val() },
            success: function(data) {
                if (data) {
                    alert(data.discount);
                    alert(data.totalAmount);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Since you're using a button I would use click event.
I am using jSon as a return object.

and this is the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Review(int number)
    {
    IVoucherRepository voucherResp = new VoucherRepository();
    IQueryable<Voucher> getVoucher = voucherResp.GetVouchers(number);
    //first check if the code is there or not else return error
    int discount = 0;
    int totalAmount = 0;
    foreach (var number in getVoucher) 
        {   
        discount = number.discount;//Thats the discount number
        }
    //after getting the discount code i need to pass that to ViewBag.TotalAmount to do   calculation

    return (Json(new { discount = discount, totalAmount = totalAmount }, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet));

    }
```

in your controller you can do all the calculations and then return a json object with all the properties you want.

Answer (score 0):

Attach a jQuery post event to the coupon button:

```
$('input[name="coupon"]').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: myUrl,
        data: {code: $('input[name="code"]').val()},
        success: function(discount) {
            /* logic here.  may need to store the code and it's discount 
               if more than one code is allowed */
        }
    });
});
```

Like ghayes mentioned though, if there are existing solutions, use those.  They will, most likely, have considered many situations unknown to you.